# What do I do if my crown molding is 1/16" too tall to fit between cabinet and ceiling?

Tags: trim

I have cabinets that go almost all the way to the ceiling and I am installing crown molding to go the rest of the way. I've gotten the nailer and the crown all assembled and went to put it on top of the cabinet and discovered it was about a 1/16" too tall to fit in a few places.

Two of the cabinets are stand-alone and I could just lower them a little bit, but there's a long run of cabinets that ends in

I have a textured ceiling, so I could theoretically sand it down, but then it would look funny in front of the molding...

Should I try cutting a 1/16" off the top of the crown with a planer or run it through my table saw or something?

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you have a piece or more left over, use that for testing the best way that looks good.  Think a table saw with a fine tooth blade would make straighter cuts than a planer(small one).

Comment: When I've lived places with that setup, I use it for storing things that are out of season or otherwise low-access - or it becomes a cat run if they bounce on up there. Closing it off, I expect you'll have happy mice once they find it. Of course, you don't have mice at your house... You can plane, saw, belt-sand. If it's only some spots, you might do better to concentrate on fitting it to the ceiling and cabinets rather than to imaginary "straightness" that may not exist in one or both of those.

Comment: Sounds like you want the molding to sit on the top of the cabinet, and not against the face of the cabinet.  Is this right?  If so, then that sort of defeats one of the purposes of molding, which is to hide slight variations in the gap between two surfaces.  Your approach requires accurate control of the space between the top of the cabinet and the ceiling, which is difficult to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a planer, use that. It's the simplest solution. if not use your table saw with a new fine tooth blade for furniture grade cuts.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, whatever cut you make should not be done at the top of the molding for two reasons:

1. When it meets up with the uncut molding the merge points both straight and curved will be off by 1/16".
2. If your cut is off at all it will be more visible than if it's at the bottom.

The best approach is to trim the molding base using a planer, sander or table saw with a very fine toothed blade. Apply tape to the molding marking off the cut line. The key if your using a hand sander/planer is to stabilize the molding while protecting the finish.
It's not a big deal if you over cut a slight bit since the cut will be in the back just above the cabinet top. You can also patch any slight imperfections with colored wood putty.